# In MySQL, set value in each row to a DATEDIFF computation on the same rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It was very tricky to figure out what to title this question, so if anyone has any ideas for improvements feel free to edit :-).

Here's the deal. I have a MySQL table that includes a bunch of donations, and there's a date for each donation. I also have a `years_active` column. I need to run a query that will `SET` the years active for every row to the difference (in years) from the first date to the last date for each unique user.

So this is my starting table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|  user_id    |   donation    |    date     | years_active |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     1       |     $10       | 2002-01-01  |     null     |
|     1       |     $15       | 2005-01-01  |     null     |
|     1       |     $20       | 2009-01-01  |     null     |
|     2       |     $10       | 2003-01-01  |     null     |
|     2       |     $5        | 2006-01-01  |     null     |
|     3       |     $15       | 2001-01-01  |     null     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is the table I'd like to achieve:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|  user_id    |   donation    |    date     | years_active |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     1       |     $10       | 2002-01-01  |     8        |
|     1       |     $15       | 2005-01-01  |     8        |
|     1       |     $20       | 2009-01-01  |     8        |
|     2       |     $10       | 2003-01-01  |     4        |
|     2       |     $5        | 2006-01-01  |     4        |
|     3       |     $15       | 2001-01-01  |     1        |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know that it's far from ideal to be storing the `years_active` redundantly in multiple rows like this. Unfortunately this table is for data visualizations and with my software I have absolutely no ability to restructure the data altogether; the `years_active` MUST be in every row.

In my research it seems like I would use subqueries to get the `MIN` value for each user id and the `MAX` value for each unique user id, and then do a `DATEDIFF` on those, and set the result to the column. But I don't really understand how I would run all these queries over and over again for every unique user.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is this possible?

Comment: How do you wish to handle partial years, e.g. a user active for 3.5 years?

Comment: Rounding to the nearest integer would be great (.5 rounding up).

Comment: So you must run a script every day in order to keep the years_active column up-to-date? Sounds horrible. Can't you at least create a view instead so as not to have to *store* the years?

Comment: No, I have an existing data set that'll be used for a visualization. This is just a one-time query to prep the data set for use within the visualization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.donation, t1.date, t2.years_active
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(YEAR(date)) - MIN(YEAR(date)) + 1 AS years_active
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

**Update:**

Here is an `UPDATE` statement which will assign the `years_active` column the correct values:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(YEAR(date)) - MIN(YEAR(date)) + 1 AS years_active
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
SET t1.years_active = t2.years_active
```

Comment: Thanks @tim-biegeleisen! This looks like purely a `SELECT`, though. How would I go about `UPDATE`ing the table and setting the values in that column (i.e. once the one-time-query has been run, the table now has the correct `years_active` values in every row)?